# Unable to show output on login of user to Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get tcmid of currently logged user in Tridion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435420/how-to-get-tcmid-of-currently-logged-user-in-tridion)

I wrote below code in class library(dll) and add assembly reference in config file od Tridion but i am unable to get any window or alert showing user.Id and its not giving any error.

[TcmExtension("Myevent")]
    public class GetInfo : TcmExtension
{

```
public GetInfo()
{
    EventSystem.Subscribe<User, LoadEventArgs>(OnUserLoad, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
}

private void OnUserLoad(User user, LoadEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phase)
{



    MessageBox.Show(user.Id);
    Console.WriteLine(user.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may be confusing event systems and GUI extensions. Your first line of code which subscribes and event handler is part of an event system, and can really only write to a log mechanism of some sort. What are you trying to achieve?

When you run your code in debug with Visual Studio on the CMS Server, does your code execute of hit any break points? Is your problem that the MessageBox doesn't show, or that your code does not run at all.

Comment: @ Chris...Code is running but neither message box nor console is coming on execution and also i cant debug it as it is an dll

Comment: Event System code runs in a background process, it is normal that you don't see anything. Try writing to a file.

Comment: Nuno.. I tried that but access denied to write a file there.
By any means can i check whether i am able to get user id at the time of login?

Comment: You should be able to debug a DLL, I debug event systems all the time for SDL Tridion. It is possible to setup remote debugging, but it is easiest if you have VS installed on your DEV CMS server. If you are not in debug, how do you know your code is running?  Please explain what your business requirement is, as I am quite certain your end goal is not to just create a popup telling a user what their ID is.

Comment: My DEV server is different from system where VS is installed.
Actually i have another application which uses core services to interact with Tridion so when i started debugging that then i got an error that create file to that location is denied which is of that event handler error, then i came to know that although my event handler code is executing but it not produces any output.

Comment: Well be frank my business requirement is to get tcmid of a user with datetime whenever he/she login to Tridion

Comment: And then do what with it? Log it somewhere to a DB? Create a report?

Comment: yes i have to keep track of each user's last login's datetime and save it to db

Comment: Then please amend your question and make it related to writing to a DB, as both @Bart and I have noted that you will not be able to create Message Boxes using this approach. You don't have a Console, and writing to a file is not actually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435420/how-to-get-tcmid-of-currently-logged-user-in-tridion), you cannot use message boxes or console.writes to see information from an event system in SDL Tridion. You will have to revert to logging to the Tridion Event Log or debug your event system.

Remote debugging is possible as described [in this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t.aspx), but I usually find it a nuisance to setup (provided you are not being blocked by firewalls between your dev machine and the CMS). So normally I simply revert to just instaling Visual Studio on the dev CMS server and debug the event system DLL directly from there, by attaching to the dllhost.exe process (see more details in this [blog post](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/debugging-tridion-2011-event-system.html)).

And like I also mentioned in my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435420/how-to-get-tcmid-of-currently-logged-user-in-tridion), I'm still not convinced you can achieve your requirements in an event system. You might need to look at a UI extension or something completely different for logging active logins of a user. Technically, you are never logging into the SDL Tridion UI, since your password is validated by IIS, and not by the SDL Tridion web application.

ps. its better to edit your question if you want to give more info, its never a good idea to open up a duplicate question.